# Microsoft Visual Studio shows a message "... stopped working ..." and restarts when I compile (build) a project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am working with "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 **Community**", under Windows10 X64, It was stable already for long time.

Recently, I installed  C++ modules (Win32, CLR , ATL, ...etc.), and started creating new projects to work with those modules .. I created some new projects, one was DirectX 12 App .. during which the windows "Settings" -> "For developers" screen appeared .. I didnt know what to do with it, I canceled the project ..

Then whenever I try to build a new, even C# project or rebuild an existing project .. I get a screen with a message:

## "*Microsoft Visual Studio Stopped working and needs to restart*"!

No new projects are building! I don't know how to restore it to stable!

**Update**

While searching around I found I can clear *ComponentModelCache* folder for VS, I tried it without success So I cleared the whole folder of Visual Studio application Data folder @ (C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\xx.0)!! I don't know the sub sequences but now I can compile my projects!

Answer (score 0):

You probably mist the windows setting 'for developers' like you described. You find the setting by searching with terms like 'for developers' in the start menu. Then enable the option. I'm not 100% sure if this will fix your problem, but this option needs to be enabled anyway.

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8PFh.jpg)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7Xwj.jpg)

I also recommend you to upgrade to Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Comment: Thanks, but no way!  cause: I tried that already 1)  I was always able to compile and run projects